Hypothesis tests for exponential growth?
Is a standard test applicable for situations involving exponential growth? I don't have a 'problem on my desk' that I need to solve. This is just a curiosity. Examples might include mitosis of bacteria or compounding interest for an investment.
In this context, we would have panel data for two different groups, observing the value, volume, cell count, etc. for each. We’d either be inferring the rates as latent variables, or otherwise testing the null hypothesis of rates being equal.
My naive approach would be

Take the logarithm $\ln y$ of the response variable $y$ for groups one and two at different times.
Use regression to fit the model $\ln y =\beta_1t + \beta_2 \text{group}_2 t + \beta_0$, conditioning on time and group two assignment.
Look at the t-test value for $\beta_2$ to determine how "unlikely" is a coefficient value of 0.


@MattF., could you list the full regression equation that you’re envisioning for clarity?

That’s a good insight. In the context of an RTC, we’d likely know the starting volumes of $group_1$ and $group_2$ randomization units (at $time=0$)

To clarify - the hypothesis being tested is whether the rate is different for group 2 - you are not testing whether the exponential growth model itself is appropriate?

@Izy - correct, in the context of the question, it is assumed that an exponential growth model is appropriate.

With hypothesis testing for exponential growth, your proposed approach of using a log-transformed response variable and linear regression seems reasonable to me. What follows is a more detailed explanation and a refined version of the model considering the comments provided in the OP, particularly those of MattF.
Model and Hypothesis
Given two groups with panel data observed over time, we want to test if the growth rates differ between the two groups. The exponential growth can be modeled as:
$$y_i(t) = y_{i0} e^{\beta_i t}$$
where $y_i(t)$ is the response variable (eg volume, cell count) for group $i$ at time $t$, $y_{i0}$ is the initial value at $t = 0$, and $\beta_i$ is the growth rate for group $i$.
Log-Transformation
To linearise the exponential growth, we take the natural logarithm of the response variable:
$$
\ln(y_i(t)) = \ln(y_{i0}) + \beta_i t
$$
For two groups, the model can be expressed as:
$$
\ln(y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \beta_2 (\text{group}_2) + \beta_3 (\text{group}_2 \cdot t)
$$
where:

$\beta_0$ is the intercept (log-initial value for group 1),
$\beta_1$ is the growth rate for group 1,
$\beta_2$ is the difference in initial values between groups (group effect at $t = 0$),
$\beta_3$ is the interaction term representing the difference in growth rates between the two groups.

Hypothesis Testing
We are particularly interested in testing whether the growth rates are the same for both groups. This corresponds to testing the null hypothesis:
$H_0: \beta_3 = 0$
versus the alternative hypothesis:
$H_a: \beta_3 \neq 0$
Regression Model
The linear regression model becomes:
$$\ln(y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \beta_2 (\text{group}_2) + \beta_3 (\text{group}_2 \cdot t) + \epsilon
$$
where $\epsilon$ is the error term.
Statistical Inference

Estimate the parameters using ordinary least squares (OLS) regression.
Conduct a t-test on the coefficient $\beta_3$. The t-test value will tell us how unlikely it is to observe the estimated $\beta_3$ under the null hypothesis $\beta_3 = 0$.

Comments and Refinements

Including $\beta_2$ allows the model to account for different starting points between the two groups, which is realistic and often necessary.

In many practical situations, the initial values of the response variable (eg cell count, investment amount) might differ between the two groups being compared. For example, in an experiment comparing the growth of bacteria under two different conditions, the initial number of bacteria might not be identical in both groups. The term $\beta_2$ in the model represents the difference in the initial values (starting points) between the two groups at time $t = 0$. By including $\beta_2$, we can account for this difference, ensuring that any observed difference in growth rates is not confounded by the difference in starting points. This adjustment makes the comparison more realistic and accurate.

In randomised controlled trials (RCTs), if the initial volumes are equal or known, the model can be simplified by setting $\beta_2$ to 0 or adjusting the intercept accordingly.

In RCTs researchers often have control over the initial conditions of the experiment. If the initial values of the response variable are equal or standardised across the groups at the start of the study, the term $\beta_2$, which accounts for differences in initial values, may become unnecessary. In such cases, $\beta_2$ can be set to 0, simplifying the model to:
$$
\ln(y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \beta_3 (\text{group}_2 \cdot t) + \epsilon
$$
Alternatively, if the initial values are known but different, the intercept $\beta_0$ can be adjusted accordingly to reflect these known initial values, effectively incorporating $\beta_2$ into the intercept term. This simplification reduces the complexity of the model while still accurately representing the growth dynamics.

The model $\ln(y / y_0) = \beta_1 t + \beta_2 (\text{group}_2 \cdot t)$ suggested by MattF can be used if the initial values are normalised, providing a simplified approach to focus solely on the growth rates.

Final Model for Hypothesis Testing
$$
\ln(y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \beta_2 (\text{group}_2) + \beta_3 (\text{group}_2 \cdot t) + \epsilon
$$
The critical step is to test $\beta_3$ using the t-test, where:

$\beta_3$ represents the differential growth rate between the two groups.
A significant t-test for $\beta_3$ (p-value < 0.05, for example) would lead us to reject $H_0$ and conclude that the growth rates differ between the groups.

Practical Steps

Fit the regression model using software (e.g., R, Python).
Examine the t-test for the interaction term ($\beta_3$).
Interpret the results to determine if there is a difference in the growth rates between the two groups.

This approach provides a robust framework for testing hypotheses about exponential growth rates using linear regression on log-transformed data.
Simulation and Visualisation
In the following we simulate some applicable data and visualise the final model and also the normalised one.
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(15)

# Simulate some data
n <- 100
time <- seq(0, 10, length.out = n)
group <- sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE)

# Parameters for the simulation
beta_0 <- 1
beta_1_group1 <- 0.3
beta_1_group2 <- 0.5
initial_value <- 10
noise <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 0.5)

# Simulated response variable
y_group1 <- initial_value * exp(beta_1_group1 * time + noise)
y_group2 <- initial_value * exp(beta_1_group2 * time + noise)
y <- ifelse(group == 0, y_group1, y_group2)

# Create DataFrame
df <- data.frame(
  time = time,
  group = group,
  y = y,
  log_y = log(y),
  log_y_y0 = log(y / initial_value)
)

# Adding interaction term
df <- df %>%
  mutate(time_group = time * group)

# Fit the first model: log(y) = beta_0 + beta_1 * time + 
# beta_2 * group + beta_3 * (group * time)
model1 <- lm(log_y ~ time + group + time_group, data = df)
summary_model1 <- summary(model1)

# Fit the second model: log(y / y0) = beta_1 * time + 
# beta_2 * (group * time)
model2 <- lm(log_y_y0 ~ time + time_group, data = df)
summary_model2 <- summary(model2)

# Print summaries
summary_model1

which results in:
Call:
lm(formula = log_y ~ time + group + time_group, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.2459 -0.3199 -0.0007  0.3204  1.2385 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.39206    0.14358  16.660  < 2e-16 ***
time         0.27294    0.02474  11.034  < 2e-16 ***
group       -0.18698    0.21940  -0.852    0.396    
time_group   0.23555    0.03794   6.208 1.36e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5469 on 96 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8423,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8374 
F-statistic: 170.9 on 3 and 96 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

summary_model2
Call:
lm(formula = log_y_y0 ~ time + time_group, data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.25893 -0.31570  0.02893  0.33794  1.22882 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.009395   0.108411   0.087    0.931    
time        0.284849   0.020381  13.977   <2e-16 ***
time_group  0.207612   0.019076  10.883   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5461 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8411,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8379 
F-statistic: 256.8 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

Now the plots:
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = log_y, color = factor(group))) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, aes(group = group)) +
  labs(title = "Model 1: log(y) vs. time", x = "Time", y = "log(y)") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())


This is a linearelised plot (obviously) and clearly shows the different growth rates (as different slopes on the plot). Now we show a plot for the untransformed data:
# Plot for Model 1 with untransformed data
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = y, color = factor(group))) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(stat = "smooth", method = "lm", formula = y ~ exp(x), 
               se = FALSE, aes(group = group)) +
  labs(title = "Model 1: y vs. time", x = "Time", y = "y") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10')  # Log scale for y-axis



Brilliant, thank you! Allowing for differences in initial volumes will be critical for any practical use case.

Philosophical question- at a minimum, how many randomization units would one desire?
Due to exponential growth, for any randomization unit, $y_{t=n+1}$ is dependent on $y_{t=n}$. However, when we take the log transform, perhaps we consider each observation as independent thus our sample size would be $NT$ ($N$ randomization units and $T$ time steps.)

Otherwise, if we believe that each randomization unit is independent (but that observations from a given randomization unit's panel data are dependent on each other), unless we carefully ensure that each randomization unit in the treatment group have the same initial value (and same for control), we would need $N$ intercepts rather than two.

Because of Jensen's inequality, you can't just exponentiate to get back to levels. To convince yourself of this regress log(y) on a constant. Exponetiates the constant. Do you get the mean of y?

@dimitriy, could you add a little more context? If I understand, you are saying that a model in log(y) space can never be used to make predictions in exp(log(y)) space. But if your point is limited to the Robert's answer, that was lost on me.

I do understand that by regressing log(y), the further $y_t$ is from 0, the less residuals are penalized. So observations closer to 0, will have a disproportionate influence on curve fitting, and invalidates assumptions of homo/heteroskedasticity... which will effect our ability to make predictions in exp(log(y)) space.

@jbuddy_13 You CAN predict under some assumptions. I think I may have misunderstood Robert's last plot and its relationship to model1 above. Let me think a bit more about it.

@robert-long any thoughts?

@jbuddy_13 yes, I do, but please bare with me, it's getting a bit late for me here today, so I probably won't respond until the morning.

Exponential growth can certainly be modeled and for each model a test can be made. But the grotth can have different mechanisms and different sources of error and you can not just throw any model at it. You need to base it on the process that generates the data.
Here is an example where bacterial growth is modeled by bacteria multiplicating after some gamma distributed waiting time. What you see is that different simulations show that the growth is initially with more randomness (due to the smaller amount of bacteria) and causes a different offset.
If you would model this with the same offset and only a difference in growth rate, then you will get bad results.
Along with this simple model there can be many other complications due to growing the bacteria and sampling the bacteria. For example, you might have several samples at different times from a single batch. Those samples give you many data points which may give a false sense of high statistical significance. You would need to use a random effects regression where each batch adds an additional source of variation (like growth conditions might be variable each experiment).

set.seed(1)

sim = function(n) {
   t = c(0) # vector to keep track of multiplication times
   tv = c(rgamma(1,4,0.5)) # vector to keep track of the upcoming multiplication for each bacteria

   for (k in 1:n) {
      k = which.min(tv) 
      time = tv[k]
      t = c(t,time)
      tv[k] = time + rgamma(1,4,0.5)
      tv = c(tv,time + rgamma(1,4,0.5))
   }
   return(t)
}

n = 10^3

### empty canvass
plot(10^6,10^6,
     xlim = c(0,70) , 
     ylim = c(1,1000),
     log = "y")

### add curves for 6 simualtions
for (i in 1:6) {
   ts = sim(n)
   lines(ts,1:(n+1), col = i, log = "y")
}


So TLDR- the model definition depends on the specific subject at hand and a one-size-fits-all model is not viable?

Exponential growth is defined as
$$y_t = y_0 \cdot (1+r)^t$$
Making growth vary by treatment group gets you
$$\frac{y_t}{y_{t-1}} = \frac{y_0 \cdot (1+r_g)^t}{y_0 \cdot (1+r_g)^{t-1}}= (1 + r_g)$$
You can estimate this with an OLS regression of the ratio on the two treatment dummies without a constant. Since you have multiple observations on the same unit over time, I would cluster the errors by unit. This will also relax the homoscedasticity assumption and allow arbitrary within-unit serial correlation in the errors. This is probably the easiest way to do this.
You can test the null that the growth rates are equal with a two-sided test that $1 + r_C = 1 + r_T$ against the alternative $1 + r_C \ne 1+r_T$.
Here's an example using Stata using a data set of 48 pigs whose weight is observed over 9 weeks:
. webuse pig, clear
(Longitudinal analysis of pig weights)

. xtset id week

Panel variable: id (strongly balanced)
 Time variable: week, 1 to 9
         Delta: 1 unit

. xtdescribe

      id:  1, 2, ..., 48                                     n =         48
    week:  1, 2, ..., 9                                      T =          9
           Delta(week) = 1 unit
           Span(week)  = 9 periods
           (id*week uniquely identifies each observation)

Distribution of T_i:   min      5%     25%       50%       75%     95%     max
                         9       9       9         9         9       9       9

     Freq.  Percent    Cum. |  Pattern
 ---------------------------+-----------
       48    100.00  100.00 |  111111111
 ---------------------------+-----------
       48    100.00         |  XXXXXXXXX

. gen treated = mod(id, 2)

. gen double ratio_weights = weight/L.weight
(48 missing values generated)

. reg ratio_weights ibn.treated, noconstant vce(cluster id) // coefl

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =        384
                                                F(2, 47)          >   99999.00
                                                Prob > F          =     0.0000
                                                R-squared         =     0.9963
                                                Root MSE          =     .07006

                                    (Std. err. adjusted for 48 clusters in id)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
ratio_weig~s | Coefficient  std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     treated |
          0  |   1.150371   .0026496   434.17   0.000      1.14504    1.155701
          1  |   1.149048   .0025254   455.01   0.000     1.143968    1.154128
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. test _b[1.treated] = _b[0.treated]

 ( 1)  - 0bn.treated + 1.treated = 0

       F(  1,    47) =    0.13
            Prob > F =    0.7195

We cannot reject the fact that the two growth rates are the same. This is to be expected since my treatment is a placebo (so $1+r_C \approx 1+r_T = 1.15$).

This definitely seems like the simplest approach with fewest assumptions. Don’t have to worry about starting values, don’t have to take the log of observed data. Just lag the column and divide.
